# In PHP 7 how would I convert this essential ternary function for my website to coalesce?

Tags: php, ternary-operator, coalescing

On my website ternary operators are used all over and I'm considering trying to update them to coalesce. This is just one example and I was hoping to get tips/suggestions on making the transition. The thing with coalesce is that it sends the first value/string it finds and so I'm not sure if this is possible with coalesce?

```
echo (
($member_logged_in == 1)
? '<a href="profile.php">My Profile</a>'
: '<a href="login.php">Login</a>'
);
```

Is it possible to turn this into coalesce or should I stick with ternary operator?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not just doing `if(!empty($member_logged_in)) echo 'profile link';`?

Comment: Actually yes, because on each one (validate or not validate) there's a specific echo statement needed. I originally had large(r) if statements and then learned about ternary operators through SO and was wondering if I should now transition to coalesce operators?

Comment: @BluTiger13 Just a sidenote, you can delete all parenthesis. They are superfluous.

Comment: Really? Eclipse PHP version was giving my yellow warning signs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're going to use integers or booleans to control template content, then you'll be stuck using logical statements.

The only two alternatives are to use the ternary default operator, or write a helper function.

```
// replace boolean with a string or null
$member_logged_in = '<a href="profile.php">My Profile</a>';
//.....
echo $member_logged_in ?: '<a href="login.php">Login</a>';
```

Use a logical function

```
function __($a,$b,$c) { return $a ? $b : $c; }
//........
echo __($member_logged_in, '<a href="profile.php">My Profile</a>', '<a href="login.php">Login</a>');
```

Ideally there shouldn't be any conditions in your templates. You could inject a variable called `$menu` that holds what links to display and the template should not care if the member is signed in or not.

Comment: Wow. I hadn't considered that. Thanks so much. I'm a hobbyist developer at heart to be honest. I could do an array...and return a lot of fun stuff.  I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

The `??` returns the first operand if it exists and is not null. You want to output a string if `$member_logged_in` is equal to `1`.

You should not be using the `??` operator in this case.

Comment: Alright thanks. I wasn't sure if there was a way I could maybe tweak it or not to get the "latest and greatest". However currently the ternary operators are working as intended right now.